# ggplot geom_tile add custom labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

With dataframe `df` below

```
df <- data.frame(model=c(rep('corolla',3),rep( 'accord',3), rep('sunny',3)),variable=c('urban_mileage', 'rural_mileage', 'highway_mileage'),rescale=rnorm(9), year=c(rep(1998,3),rep( 1997,3), rep(2003,3)))

> df
    model        variable     rescale year
1 corolla   urban_mileage -0.73386453 1998
2 corolla   rural_mileage  0.21467425 1998
3 corolla highway_mileage -1.75450160 1998
4  accord   urban_mileage -0.08467004 1997
5  accord   rural_mileage -1.60112730 1997
6  accord highway_mileage  2.26943695 1997
7   sunny   urban_mileage  0.31349626 2003
8   sunny   rural_mileage -0.32768735 2003
9   sunny highway_mileage -0.04645053 2003
```

I'm creating a heatmap using geom_tile as follows

```
ggplot(df, aes(variable, model)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), colour = "white") +
     scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "white", high = "green") +
     labs(x = "",y = "") +
     theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
           axis.text.x = element_text(angle=30,hjust=1,vjust=1.0),
           axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12))
```

This gives a heat-map representation of mileage by road type as shown in the image at the end. However I want to add `year` along with the current y-axis tick mark labels as text below the `model` name in brackets - i.e instead of the current y-axis tick mark labels it shall instead show

```
sunny
(2003)

corolla
(1998)

accord
(1997)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:?

```
ggplot(df, aes(variable, model)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), colour = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "white", high = "green") +
  labs(x = "",y = "") + scale_y_discrete(labels=paste(unique(df$model),paste0("(",unique(df$year),")"),sep="\n")) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=30,hjust=1,vjust=1.0),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see the intended results - its turns the y-axis labels to `NA` `NA` `()`

Comment: Running this code seems to work for me! Can you produce the `paste(...)` part outside of the ggplot code?

Comment: can you elaborate on `produce the paste(...) part outside of the ggplot code`. Also why do the plot looks different ?

Comment: It's just to see if this produces the right output `paste(unique(df$model),paste0("(",unique(df$year),")"),sep="\n")`  should look like  "corolla\n(1998)" "accord\n(19.... . The plots/colors look different because you sample from rnorm(9) so the rescale values differ each time you plot it. What is your ggplot2 version?

Comment: my apologies - I tried this again and it is giving the expected output.

Comment: Is there a way to set the color of `(year)` to a different color based on the value ?

Comment: np :) Hmm that's a bit tricky, you can change the color in `theme()` as in `axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12,color=c("red","blue","green")))` but I don't think you can manually adjust only the year part. One option is to add the year using `annotate` in the margin and assign it an option but that is a bit of a ugly workaround